# Convert pandas date object to integer of form YYYYMMDD

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a date column in my pandas dataframe in the form of YYYY-MM-DD, I need to convert this to a integer in the form YYYYMMDD. I have been at it for a long time now and can't find a simple solution.

Comment: Am i right in understanding you want to convert it from a datetime or string to an integer of that form? try: `x = int(str(x).replace('-', ''))` where x is your value. If you don't want to do this you may need to be more specific in your question...

Answer (score 4):

If your pandas column is datetime dtype then use datetime access `.dt` and `strftime`, if you are talking about a datetimeindex then you don't need the `.dt`:

```
df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: `df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)` to fulfill OP's task.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
df['column_to_change']=df['column_to_change'].str.replace('-','').apply(int)
```

it will change all strings (or datetime) in your column `column_to_change` of you DataFrame `df` into format YYYYMMDD with the type integer as you can check with:

```
df.dtypes
```